# R УДАЛЕНИЕ значений

Tags: r

У меня есть список со значениями "a","b","c","d".
И есть датафрейм df:

```
a|78|99
a|dn|d
b|d|jjj
c|jk|jk
c|jkl|kdl
f|fj|fg
```

Мне нужно удалить строки, содержащие в первом столбце значения из списка

Comment: [google://r+delete+rows+by+value](https://www.statology.org/r-remove-rows-from-data-frame-condition/)

Answer (score 1):

Данные лучше скидывать с помощью `reprex` или `dput()`. В целом, вы спрашиваете о базовой операции фильтрования колонки по значению. Александр в комменте вам скинул нормальную ссылку на материал; я дополню ответом кодом.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# подготовим данные

filter_values <- c("a","b","c","d")

df <- tibble::tribble(~col1, ~col2, ~col3,
                      "a", "78", "99",
                      "a", "dn", "d",
                      "b", "d", "jjj",
                      "c", "jk", "jk",
                      "c", "jkl", "kdl",
                      "f", "fj", "fg")
# dplyr подход

df %>% filter(!col1 %in% filter_values)

# data.table подход

df %>% setDT() %>% .[!col1 %in% filter_values, , ]
```